# Bootstrap 3 and masnory

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, grid, jquery-masonry

By using **Bootstrap 3** and **Masonry**, I want display my 8 photos like this :

the desired result  :

[image]

for this, I write this code :

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="row">

        <div class="items">

            <div class="item col-md-3">
                <img src="...." alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="item col-md-3">
                <img src="...." alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="item col-md-3">
                <img src="...." alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="item col-md-3">
                <img src="...." alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="item col-md-3">
                <img src="...." alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="item col-md-3">
                <img src="...." alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="item col-md-3">
                <img src="...." alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="item col-md-3">
                <img src="...." alt="...">
            </div>

     </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
var $container = $('.items');

$container.imagesLoaded( function() {

  $container.masnory({
    columnWidth: '.item',
    itemSelector: '.item'
  });

});
```

but I get this result :

[image]

Why the photos is not in order ? How can make this working ?

Any advice will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle or something?

Comment: Masonry will try to rearrange the items, and fill available space with items. This results unordering.